# HTML Table Filter Script + sortable table: Always show tfoot and thead

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I use [this](http://tablefilter.free.fr) wonderful script to make my table sortable and add some filters to it. My problem is that I need always to see the second row in the thead (that with the checkbox) . I avoided sorting the row when clicked (by making it td instead th although it's in the thead).

So the main problem is that I need to see the checkbox (thead/td, and it shouldn't be active when clicked to sort the table as the row above) and also always see the tfoot - which is also hidden when add filter...

Here are my settings

```
var Props =  {
          popup_filters: true,
          mark_active_columns: true,
          sort: true,
          sort_config: {  
            sort_types:['EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU']  
          },  
          loader: true,  
          loader_html: '<img src="/images/load.gif" style="vertical-align:middle; margin:0 5px 0 5px"><span>Зареждане...</span>',
          mark_active_columns: true,
          col_0: "select",  
            col_1: "multiple",  
            col_2: "select",  
            col_3: "select",
            cEUtom_slc_options: {  
        cols:[1],  
        texts: [['0- 50','60 - 80','80 - 100']],  
        values: [  
                    ['<=50','>60 && <=80','>80 && <=100']  
                ],  
        sorts: [false],
        sort_config: {  
            sort_types:['EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU']  
        }, 
    },   
    themes: {   
    name:['MyTheme'],   
    src:['TableFilter/TF_Themes/MyTheme/MyTheme.css'],   
    description:['My stylesheet'],   
    initialize:[null]  
} 
        };
          setFilterGrid("advancedtable1",Props );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I needed
first what we need to do is to get the row number of the footer:
`var totRowIndex = tf_Tag(tf_Id('advancedtable1'),"tr").length; //advancedtable1 is the table id`
then I added this 
`rows_always_visible:[2,totRowIndex]` to the table props where 2 is the row in the th wich i wanted to always see and totRowIndex is the footer row.